# LinkedBlockingQueue node's next is not volatile

Tags: java, volatile

I'm reading LinkedBlockingQueue code now, but i have a question, maybe it's simple, but i can't find answer, really need help.

I noticed the Node.next is not volatile, like this:

```
static class Node<E> {
    E item;
    LinkedBlockingQueue.Node<E> next;

    Node(E var1) {
        this.item = var1;
    }
}
```

**So, how does the enqueue of a new node (Node.next) become visible to the dequeue via another thread?**

```
private void enqueue(Node<E> node) {
    // assert putLock.isHeldByCurrentThread();
    // assert last.next == null;
    last = last.next = node;
}

 private E dequeue() {
    // assert takeLock.isHeldByCurrentThread();
    // assert head.item == null;
    Node<E> h = head;
    Node<E> first = h.next;
    h.next = h; // help GC
    head = first;
    E x = first.item;
    first.item = null;
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods `enqueue()` and `dequeue()` are private, and thus are invoked ONLY from other methods within that same class, such as `peek()`, `poll()`, `put()`, `offer()`, etc.

Locking is enforced at a higher level and there's never a chance for two threads to access a node's instance variables at the same time in a race condition.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Both put thread and take thread, they operate the node list head and last point to. Put thread calls enqueue method and take thread calls dequeue method. In enqueue method last.next is set, but it's not volatile.So when dequeue method operates head.next, how can it read the next set before in enqueue method because of thread cache?

Comment: oh,i see.  Enqueue and dequeue method both are surrounded by lock.lock() and lock.unlock(), which implies volatile semantic as java happen-before memory model.

Comment: Except on 32-bit ARM using AdoptOpenJDK where there seems to be a wonky race condition. 2022-07-08T07:23:47.065812+00:00 APP-277269 bash[370]: Exception in thread "DBus-Signal-Receiver-1" java.lang.NullPointerException ... 2022-07-08T07:23:47.072822+00:00 APP-277269 bash[370]: #011at java.base/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.dequeue(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:217)